# how to use npm and github to work on 2 projects at once

Tags: github, npm

I am working on 2 projects (say p1 and p2) that are github npm modules. P1 depends on p2. I need to modify them both (tweak p2 then change p1 to take advantage of tweak). I dont see how to do this. I change p2, gulp build it, test it. Now what, how do I make the output of p2 build get picked up by the gulp build of p1

I am an absolute npm and github beginner; so this is just plain ignorance on my part - but I have consulted goolepedia extensively to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after more RTM

in p1 directory do `npm link <path to p2>`